# Colocando data e hora em um backup em arquivo .sh

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, backup

Estou utilizando um script para fazer meu backup de banco de dados que tenho no MySQL, estou com dúvida de como colocar a **data e hora** do backup ao invéz de só a data:

Ele fica assim:

```
alex_banco-2019-05-28.sql
```

Mas eu queria que ficasse assim:

```
alex_banco-2019-05-28:13:18:51.sql
```

Seria possível fazer isso esse tipo de mudança?

```
 Definindo parametros do MySQL
echo "  -- Definindo parametros do MySQL ..."
DB_NAME='atrizes'
DB_USER='alex'
DB_PASS='123456'
DB_PARAM='--add-drop-table --add-locks --extended-insert --single-transaction -quick'

# Definindo parametros do sistema
echo "  -- Definindo parametros do sistema ..."
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
MYSQLDUMP=/usr/bin/mysqldump
BACKUP_DIR=/home/alex/backup
BACKUP_NAME=alex_banco-$DATE.sql
BACKUP_TAR=ales_banco-$DATE.tar

#Gerando arquivo sql
echo "  -- Gerando Backup da base de dados $DB_NAME em $BACKUP_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME ..."
$MYSQLDUMP $DB_NAME $DB_PARAM -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS > $BACKUP_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME

# Compactando arquivo em tar
echo "  -- Compactando arquivo em tar ..."
tar tar -cjf $BACKUP_DIR/$BACKUP_TAR -C $BACKUP_DIR $BACKUP_NAME --remove-files

# Excluindo backups antigos
echo " -- Excluindo backups com mais de 30 dias ..."
find $BACKUP_DIR/* -mtime +30 -delete
```

Comment: Esta não é uma dúvida relativa ao MySQL e sim ao shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retirando os especificadores de formatação da `manpage` de `date`.

```
FORMAT controls the output.  Interpreted sequences are:
%F     full date; same as %Y-%m-%d 
%H     hour (00..23)
%M     minute (00..59)
%S     second (00..60)
%T     time; same as %H:%M:%S
```

Que traduzido (por mim):

```
FORMATO controla a saída. As sequências interpretadas são:
%F     data completa; o mesmo que %Y-%m-%d
%H     hora (00..23)
%M     minuto (00..59)
%S     segundo (00..60)
%T     tempo; mesmo que %H:%M:%S
```

Então podes tentar:

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%T`
```

ou

```
DATE=`date +%F:%T`
```

ou

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`
```

Use `man date` no seu terminal para obter mais informações.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar assim:

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%I:%M`
```

Comment: %H e %I representam ambos horas, mas em formatos diferentes.